# Symfony, how to set the member as active or not

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i'm useing symfony in my project and i used this code in twig to show active or disactive button on my members list

```
{% for item in members %}
<form action="{{dol_url()}}/m71Verein/app.php/member/showList/edit/{{id}}" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <td>{{item.contact.fullname}}</td>
        {% if item.state == 1 %}
            <td><button type="submit" value="{{item.id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Deaktivieren</button></td>
        {% else %}
            <td><button type="submit" value="{{item.id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Aktivieren</button></td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
</form>
```

but i want to know now, how to change the value after i clicked the button to change the value from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 0

Comment: Please add the controller code for member/showList/edit/{id}

Comment: I suggest adding a route name so you can use the path function in twig to print URLs, you can also simplify the if/else so you don't have to repeat the button. http://pastebin.com/eGq5T4Jy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click in the button will submit the form to the route mathed in the action.

```
{% for item in members %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{item.contact.fullname}}
        </td>
        <td>
            <form action="{{dol_url()}}/m71Verein/app.php/member/showList/edit/{{item.id}}" method="POST">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
                    {% if item.state == 1 %}
                        Deaktivieren
                    {% else %}
                        Aktivieren
                    {% endif %}
                </button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

In your controller add/edit your action the toggle the item status:

```
public function toggleAction(ItemClassName $item)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $item->setStatus(!$item->getStatus());

    $em->merge($item);
    $em->flush();

    // return to list
    return $this->redirectToRoute('<item_listing_route_name>');
}
```

Where `ItemClassName` is the class of your entity.